# How can I add an article to a region?

Tags: 7, theming

How can I add a content (let's say content of Article type)' to ANY region (not only in content region), or how to add a region to a node view page?

Comment: welcome to drupal, please learn how to ask question, you question is not clear.
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I wonder how I can add an Article to ANY region (not only in content region) ??

Answer (score 1):

By default drupal don't let you do this , you should achieve it with this two solution

1. use [nodeblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeblock)

> This module allows you to specify content type(s) as being a block.
>   This allows the content managers of the site to edit the block text
>   and title without having to access the block administration page.
>   Users only need edit access to that node in order to edit it.
>
> We advice you to use this module together with Node Level Blocks or
>   Block Reference module.
>
> It is very handy to create a simple block content type and enable this
>   content type for blocks and use these in place of the normal 'add
>   block' functionality.

2. Achieve it by views block,I mean create a view, get result of it with what you want ,then save it as block ( I mean create block view), then put the block in the region you want.

Comment: Views would be better, honestly.